# How to implement `visitor' pattern in non-oop languages?

Tags: design-patterns

**visitor** pattern makes use of oop mechanism, especially **polymorphism**. This pattern is useful in implementing parsers, where a number of tokens must be processed on their own right. But for non-oop languages, e.g. C, what is the solution? I guess that a long string of **switch-case** control statements is for the purpose.

Answer (score 3):

OOP languages aren't any more special than imperative languages, asides from some nice type-checking and syntactic sugar. Other than that, there's nothing much separating C from basic Java or C++. Many OOP-like features can (and are) implemented in non-OOP languages. For example, it is common in C to define `struct`s and functions that operate on these `struct`s (usually by taking them as their first argument). Virtual or abstract methods are nothing more than callbacks.

I'm going to steal an [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) from Wikipedia here. Suppose you have a hierarchy of 3d objects for a CAD program that you want to save using the visitor pattern. Our object hierarchy contains lines, circles, arcs, and triangles. You want to have one visitor for OBJ files and the other for 3DS files.

First let's define our visitor structure:

```
typedef struct _Visitor {
    void (*visitLine)(struct _Visitor *, Line *);
    void (*visitCircle(struct _Visitor *, Circle *);
    void (*visitArc)(struct _Visitor *, Arc *);
    void (*visitTriangle)(struct _Visitor *, Triangle *);
} Visitor;
```

Notice how each callback method in `Visitor` takes a `struct _Visitor` as its first argument. This argument is semantically equivalent to `this` (or `self`) in OOP languages, according to our calling convention. This allows us to store extra data with the `Visitor`, by making `Visitor` the first field in our file format-specific Visitors.

Now we can define a visitor for the OBJ and 3DS format:

```
typedef struct _OBJVisitor {
    struct _Visitor visitor;
    int objSpecific1; // This is just an example, these fields can be whatever you want, 
    ...              // the key is that the struct _Visitor is the first element, 
    ...              // because this lets us freely cast between Visitor and OBJVisitor
 } OBJVisitor;

 typedef struct __3DSVisitor {
    struct _Visitor visitor;
    int _3dsSpecific1;
    ...
 } _3DSVisitor; // C names can't start with a number...
```

Now, we will define two constructors for this structure that return a `Visitor` specific to one of these structures. Note how we freely convert between the generic `Visitor` and either `OBJVisitor` or `_3DSVisitor`, this freedom to convert across platforms is guaranteed by the C standard.

```
Visitor *mkOBJVisitor(int objSpecific1, ...) { // The constructor can take any other arguments as necessary
    OBJVisitor* objVisitor = (OBJVisitor *) malloc(sizeof(OBJVisitor));
    objVisitor->visitor.visitLine = OBJVisitor_visitLine;
    objVisitor->visitor.visitCircle = OBJVisitor_visitCircle;
    objVisitor->visitor.visitArc = OBJVisitor_visitArc;
    objVisitor->visitor.visitTriangle = OBJVisitor_visitTriangle;
    objVisitor->objSpecific1 = objSpecific1;
    return (Visitor *) objVisitor;
 }

 void OBJVisitor_visitLine(struct _Visitor *_this, Line *line)
 {
     OBJVisitor *this = (OBJVisitor *) this; // This convertibility is guaranteed.
     ... // implementation of line serialization
 }
```

I'm omitting the functions for 3DS and the other `OBJVisitor_*` functions, since they're all similar.

Now, we can use the same trick and create an `Acceptor` struct for each of our objects:

```
typedef struct _Acceptor {
    void (*accept)(struct _Acceptor *, Visitor *);
} Acceptor;

typedef struct Circle {
    Acceptor acceptor;
    double radius;
    double x, y;
    ... // Any other information you want
}

... // Define similar structures for the other shapes
```

Now, in our shape constructors, we can set the appropriate acceptor callback.

```
Circle *mkCircle(double radius, double x, double y)
{
    Circle *circle = (Circle *) malloc(sizeof(Circle));
    circle->acceptor.accept = Circle_accept;
    circle->radius = radius;
    circle->x = x;
    circle->y = y;
    return circle;
 }
```

The `Circle_accept` method will invoke the appropriate `visit*` function on the `Visitor`.

```
 void Circle_accept(struct _Acceptor *_this, Visitor *visitor)
 {
     visitor->visitCircle(visitor, (Circle *) _this);
 }
```

Note how we pass in `visitor` as the first argument to `visitor->visitCircle`. Because C does not have built-in support for OOP, it won't automatically pass in the "object" we're invoking the `visitCircle` method on. But this isn't too much of an issue, because we can always do it ourselves.

Now, suppose there a group object that contained these shapes as children, and was itself an acceptor:

```
typedef struct _Group {
    Acceptor acceptor;
    int childCount;
    Acceptor **children;
} Group;

Group *mkGroup(int childCount, Acceptor** children)
{
    Group *group = (Group *) malloc(sizeof(Group));
    group->acceptor.accept = Group_accept;
    ... // Omitting code for clarity
}
```

Now, we can arrange our shape into a hierarchy, and visit every single shape, simply by calling accept on our highest level `Group`.

```
void Group_accept(struct _Acceptor *_this, Visitor *visitor)
{
    Group *this = (Group *) this;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < this->childCount; ++i) {
       this->children[i]->accept(this->children[i], visitor); // Invoke the visitor on each of our children, including any group nodes.
    }
 }
```

As you can see, OOP is just an extension of imperative programming. Above, we've implemented interfaces, inheritance, virtual (or abstract) methods, and constructors in plain old C. You can extend these ideas to create whole object systems, and from there, it is trivial to create the visitor pattern. The only hiccup is that, unless you stick to a well-defined coding and naming convention, it is easy to get yourself in a mess with callbacks, memory leaks, etc.

Happy (and careful) coding!

Comment: Looks good except one detail. In your code `this->children[i]->accept(visitor);`, I don't think C will implicitly pass `children[i]` to the `accept` function, whose declaration requires `struct _Acceptor *, Visitor *`.

Comment: You're right, of course. Fixed now.